# Compiler change my LOTAnimationView to AnimationView

Tags: swift

```swift
import UIKit
import Lottie

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        let animationView = LOTAnimationView(name: "Like")// Use of unresolved identifier 'LOTAnimationView'; did you mean 'AnimationView'?
        animationView.frame = self.containerView.bounds
        self.containerView.addSubview(animationView)
        animationView.play()
        animationView.loopAnimation = true

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no `LOTAnimationView`. It's `AnimationView` per the [docs](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios#quick-start) if you're using Lottie 3. `LOTAnimationView` existed in version 2. The [migration guide](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios/blob/master/Documentation/MIGRATING.md#class-changes) explains the constants that were renamed.

Comment: Sorry, but could you add code, how can I add a switch animation

Comment: Just change `LOTAnimationView` to `AnimationView`.

Comment: This is correct answer And it worked for me.

Comment: If you have number of errors in many file and dont want to change class name everywhere. Just change Lottie version Like: `pod 'lottie-ios', '2.5.2'`

Comment: The latest migration guide, http://airbnb.io/lottie/#/ios-migration

Comment: `lottie-ios 4.3.3` update - `AnimationView` to `LottieAnimationView`

Answer (score 3):

If you use version > 4.0.0 of Lottie you must rename `AnimationView`/`LOTAnimationView` to `LottieAnimationView`.

For example:

```
@IBOutlet weak var view_animated: LottieAnimationView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
  
   view_animated.animation = LottieAnimation.named("name_your_file.json")
   view_animated.play()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it's changed to "Lottie.LottieAnimationView"

````
```     var animationView:Lottie.LottieAnimationView!
````

...

```
     init(){
    self.overlayView = UIView()
    self.animationView = Lottie.LottieAnimationView(name: "first")
```

}```